# Solr: Newly Observed facets

Tags: solr, faceted-search

I have two fields in my solr index data: "userName" and "startTimeISO" along with many other fields. 
Now I want to query for all the "userNames" that were seen TODAY but not seen in the last 30 days. 
Basically, I am trying to find out Newly Observed UserNames for today.

Now the Solr Facet query I am running is:

```
facet.pivot: "userName,startTimeISO",
fq: " NOT startTimeISO:["2014-12-20T00:00:00.000Z" TO "2015-01-18T00:00:00.000Z"] AND startTimeISO:["2015-01-19T00:00:00.000Z" TO "2015-01-20T00:00:00.000Z"]"
```

But I am for some reason getting incorrect results. 
For example, I see userName: "bla" the above query. 
If I run the same query for tomorrow, I am again see "bla" in my Facet Results.

I am some how not able to get the correct logic. Perhaps I am not using all the tools provided by solr, which I am unaware of?

Can someone help me here. I dont mind testing all of your suggestions and coming back and forth with different suggestions.

In the meanwhile I am looking online to see if there is some other way to facet.

Update:
**SOLUTION:**

In case your data looks like:

```
"id": "1",
"userName": "one",
"startTimeISO": "2015-01-20T17:24:32.888Z"

"id": "2",
"userName": "one",
"startTimeISO": "2015-01-16T17:24:50.208Z"

"id": "3",
"userName": "two",
"startTimeISO": "2015-01-20T17:25:06.109Z"
```

You could use the below query combination:

```
q=*:*
fq=startTimeISO:[NOW-1DAY TO NOW]  //this will give you all the users that
were seen today
fq=-_query_:"{!join from=userName to=userName}startTimeISO:[NOW-30DAYS TO
NOW-1DAYS]"  //dont include those documents that have others with the same
name and were viewed during the last 30 days.
```

Thanks to Alvaro Cabrerizo for helping me out. 
Here is the link to the same question on Solr mailing list: 
http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Newly-observed-Facets-td4180538.html

Comment: Nice solution! It's worth pointing out that this'll work for single-shard collections but not multiple.

Comment: what do you mean?
We have a solr cluster with 5 shards. and it works for me when I run the query.

Comment: It may seem to work but a 'join' query only operates on the local shard/index; it isn't distributed.  So you may see user names coming back that haven't been filtered out because the shard that thought it was unique in 30 days was unaware of another shard that had the user in the 30 day window.  If you shard by user, you should be okay since this keeps a user's data local to a shard.  And FYI the -_query_:"..." syntax is old; as of v4.1 (or maybe 4.2?) you can remove that and put a 'NOT'. Furthermore you may want to combine the 'fq's into one but not essential.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one query that will do what you want.  Your best bet is to first query for the user names seen today (a smaller number than all those in the last 30) returning that list to your client.  A typical 'fq' querying for the last day will select those documents, and then facet.field=username with facet.limit=1000000 unfortunately high and facet.mincount=1.  Now that you have this list on your client, submit a large query to Solr for faceting on the username field again and with a filter query for the next 29 days (don't include today), and an additional filter query to match just the usernames you found in the first query.  Ideally the username filter would use the 'terms' QParser in Solr 4.10 but it's not essential. When this second query returns, this will show you which of the usernames seen today were also seen in the subsequent 29 days. With that information, you can subtract the sets of names and you have the usernames seen today.

Comment: yes. That would not be optimal. There can be millions of facets returned by the query. 
I am updating the question with my answer. Hope it helps